# java: save string as gzip file

Tags: java, string, gzip, compression

I'm java beginner, I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649485/how-to-compress-a-string):

```
String2GzipFile (String file_content, String file_name)
String2GzipFile("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", "lorem.txt.gz")
```

I cant figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are two orthogonal concepts here:

- Converting text to binary, typically through an `OutputStreamWriter`
- Compressing the binary data, e.g. using `GZIPOutputStream`

So in the end you'll want to:

- Create an `OutputStream` which writes to wherever you want the result (e.g. a file or in memory via a `ByteArrayOutputStream`
- Wrap that `OutputStream` in a `GZIPOutputStream`
- Wrap the `GZIPOutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` using an appropriate charset (e.g. UTF-8)
- Write the text to the `OutputStreamWriter`
- Close the writer, which will flush and close everything else.

For example:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
try {
  Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(output), "UTF-8");
  try {
    writer.write(text);
  } finally {
    writer.close();
  }
 } finally {
   output.close();
 }
```

Note that I'm closing `output` even if we fail to create the writer, but we still need to close `writer` if everything is successful, in order to flush everything and finish writing the data.

Comment: I was trying using ByteArrayOutputStream, but your example works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @user752679: I originally wrote out a sample using ByteArrayOutputStream, but as your question says you want to write it to a file...

Comment: note: dont forget to close the `streamWriter` or else you will get `unexpected EOF` while trying to open up `*.gzip` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12100352/432903

Answer (score 4):

Same solution as Jon, just used try with resources

```
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("filename.gz");
     Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(output), "UTF-8")) {
    
    writer.write("someText");
}
```

Comment: also, it's probably preferrable to use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `"UTF-8"`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [GZIPOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) - you should be able to use this in exactly the same way as any other outputstream to write to a file - it'll just automatically write it in the gzip compressed format.