# Java zip file created but not opening up, says unexpected end of file

Tags: java, gzip

I have a `Object` as

```
private String name;
private int age;
private String country;
// getters and setters
```

and functions are

```
protected void write(@Nonnull final Document document, @Nonnull final OutputStream stream) throws PersistenceException {
        try {
            jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(document, stream);
        } catch (final JAXBException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new PersistenceException("Failed to marshall document " + docment.getUniqueId() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

I convert this into `zip` file as

```
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           write(document, stream);
           GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getOutputFilePath(document.getUniqueId()))));
           gzipOutputStream.write(stream.toByteArray());
```

This creates the zip file, but when I try to open it up, it says

```
gzip: document.xml.gz: unexpected end of file
```

What is that I am not doing right here?

Comment: Do you close opened gzip output stream?

Comment: that was it, i did `flush()` and `close()` and it worked, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make sure to call:

```
gzipOutputStream.flush();
```

and eventually

```
gzipOutputStream.close();
```