# Compress a string to gzip in Java

Tags: java, gzip, gunzip

```
public static String compressString(String str) throws IOException{
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return str;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    Gdx.files.local("gziptest.gzip").writeString(out.toString(), false);
    return out.toString();
}
```

When I save that string to a file, and run `gunzip -d file.txt` in unix, it complains:

```
gzip: gzip.gz: not in gzip format
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a [FileOutputStream (in place of the ByteArrayOutputStream)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994674/java-save-string-as-gzip-file)? Have you tried what happens then?

Comment: It's libgdx, which is a cross-platform game development library. I only wrote it to a file to troubleshooting. I've actually been trying to send the string via http POST request to my flask server, but the server side complained that the string isn't valid gzip.

Comment: I guess that the problem is your conversion of the compressed data to a string. I think you should treat the result as a byte[]. Can libgdx write a byte[] to a file?

Comment: It can. Try Gdx.files.local("gziptest.gzip").writeBytes(out.getBytes(), false). What happens?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use `BufferedWriter`

```
public static String compressString(String str) throws IOException{
if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
    return str;
}

BufferedWriter writer = null;

try{
    File file =  new File("your.gzip")
    GZIPOutputStream zip = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zip, "UTF-8"));

    writer.append(str);
}
finally{           
    if(writer != null){
     writer.close();
     }
  }
 }
```

About your code example try:

```
public static String compressString(String str) throws IOException{
if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
    return str;
}
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(str.length());
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
gzip.write(str.getBytes());
gzip.close();

byte[] compressedBytes = out.toByteArray(); 

Gdx.files.local("gziptest.gzip").writeBytes(compressedBytes, false);
out.close();

return out.toString(); // I would return compressedBytes instead String
}
```

Comment: That makes a valid gzip object. I'm really looking to return a string though. Can I bypass writing the file?

Comment: For your example try first: `ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(str.length());`

Comment: Take a look on my edit I posted above, I changed your code a bit

Comment: That works. At some point I have to convert it to string to send up to my flask application-- why do you recommend returning as a `byte[]`?

Comment: because its unreadable String I think, IDK what you want to do with that after. If you send `byte[]` you can after decompress it back

Comment: Ok that clears up my confusion. (Thank you.) I'm sending touch screen log data from my game up to my server so I can do analytics on it later. I'm going to base64 encode the byte[] for sending up. I think that will work if I understand things correctly.

Comment: @Downvoter please give description why down-vote. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try that :

```
//...

String string = "string";

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename.zip");

GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
gzos.write(string.getBytes());
gzos.finish();

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Save bytes from out with FileOutputStream

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("gziptest.gz");
fos.write(out.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```

out.toString() seems suspicious, the result will be unreadable, if you dont care then why not to return byte[], if you do care it would look better as hex or base64 string.

Comment: agree, i would return `byte[]` from `out.toByteArray()`