# Convert XML to binary in Java

Tags: java

I want to convert XML into binary data in Java? What is the fastest and easiest way to do this?

Is there any internal Java method that I can use?

Comment: This is not clear; you need to describe what type of binary file you're thinking of.

Comment: For example Base64? What kind of binary data do you know?

Comment: @user1285928: Maybe it would be clearer if you describe the goal here.  What do you want to use this binary file for?

Comment: Here is the idea: I want to create XML data, convert it into binary data and send it to another computer on the network.

Comment: @user1285928: Why don't you just send the XML?

Comment: @Danubian: Please do not edit questions to a) add words to the OP's mouth, and b) so that existing answers are invalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just compress the xml then you can read it and use either GZIPOutputStream or ZipOutputstream as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649485/how-to-compress-a-string).

Comment: Which is format will be more efficient - binary xml or compressed XML?

Comment: Compression is a way of expressing the same data in a fewer number of bits.

Comment: binary XML is 95% effective on XML structure, so probably binary XML.