# How to zip a single string with ZipOutputStream and save as a readable string

Tags: java, android

I tried to compress a string with DeflaterOutputStream and converted the output with base64 to save the result in another string

```
public static String compress(String str) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    java.util.zip.Deflater compresser = new java.util.zip.Deflater(java.util.zip.Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true);
    DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(stream, cozmpresser);
    deflaterOutputStream.write(data);
    deflaterOutputStream.close();
    byte[] output = stream.toByteArray();
    return Base64Coder.encodeLines(output);
}
```

Now i wish to try ZipOutputStream. i tried

```
public static String compress(String str) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(stream);
    deflaterOutputStream.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
    deflaterOutputStream.setLevel(8);
    deflaterOutputStream.write(data);
    deflaterOutputStream.close();
    byte[] output = stream.toByteArray();
    return Base64Coder.encodeLines(output);
}
```

But dont work. ZipOutputStream seems orientated to a structure of folders and files
how can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649485/how-to-compress-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipOutputStream` is intended to produce a [Zip file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29), which, as you noticed, is generally used as a container for files and folders (a "compressed folder" or "compressed directory tree", in other words).

If you merely want to compress a string and then convert it to some printable form, `ZipOutputStream` isn't really the right choice. `GZIPOutputStream` is more appropriate to that purpose, in my opinion.

Since you marked this question with an *android* tag, note the comment here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html

*Using GZIPOutputStream is a little easier than ZipOutputStream because GZIP is only for compression, and is not a container for multiple files.*

Comment: GZIPOutputStream seems goob but have no fast options. I'm trying to change compression using
**OutputStream gzipout = new GZIPOutputStream(stream){{def.setLevel(java.util.zip.Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);}};**
but I wish to remove headers too. Every Base64 string starts with H4sIAAAAAAAAA. There is a setting to avoid headers to be writted?