# Convert Base64 String to a Shorter String in JAVA Android

Tags: java, android, base64

I am trying to convert a `Base64` string of an image to shorter string. Currently its length is 150356 characters. Is there any way to convert this string under 4000 characters? I have tried `MD5` hash but its not working for a longer string.

I am using below code to convert captured image to `Base64` in android.

```
public String uriToBase64(Uri uri){
    String encodedImage = null;
    try{
        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        encodedImage = encodeImage(selectedImage);
    }catch (Exception e){
        encodedImage = "";
    }

    return encodedImage;
}
```

Comment: [how-to-compress-a-string-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649485/how-to-compress-a-string-in-java)

Comment: you  will be unable to compress your string by 40 times I think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base 64 encode and decode example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code)

Comment: How did you achieve it?