# How to compress huge string without losing any chars?

Tags: javascript, java

I have that kind of strings inside my adress bar:

[image]

Generally that chars are from UTF-8.

**Is this possible to compress that kind of string to a smaller form?** For example, it could be in the form of approximately 1-2 lines.

I mean compress it in controller Spring, and uncompress in JavaScript.
Anyone have some idea?

Comment: There is a lot of repetition there, so yes, it could be compressed significantly. But data that large probably shouldn't be in a URL to begin with

Comment: Also why do these have to be part of the url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compress a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649485/how-to-compress-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Well this is parametr sended from Spring controller to JavaScript. I used model.addAtribute. I just don't know other way to do it :<

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is very very long. If you want send this bigger data, you can do it on body of request, why are you using the URL?

Comment: well sorry i am newbie i don't know all "best ways"

Comment: and what is your expectations from this request? What did you want to do?

Comment: I just wanted send huge JSON data from spring Controller to javascript method.

Comment: May be you are making mistake, you cannot send from Spring to Javascript. You can use javascript to send request to Spring. This is the correct approach.